# Execute A Jupyter notebook file using runipy -o myfile.ipynb command upon Raspberry PI 4(Raspbian OS) boot-up

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, python-3, cron, systemd-startup

My research regarding this issue: All methods available on the internet are about running .py files on Raspberry Pi boot.
NO ACTUAL HELP ABOUT RUNNING JUPYTER NOTEBOOK FILES .ipynb ON RASPBERRY BOOT IS THERE.

Up till now, I have **succeeded** in running a Jupyter Notebook .ipynb file from the **command terminal** of Raspberry Pi 4. I achieved this by using the command "**runipy -o myfile.ipynb**" in the command terminal  after installing runipy, and the code seems to run just fine as it would in the Jupyter Notebook browser.

But the problem I am facing right now is that I **cannot** seem to Execute this command("runipy -o myfile.ipynb") **on raspberry pi bootup** for my project.

Note: I have already used the **rc.local** method but the launcher.sh file does not recognize runipy. This rc.local method will work fine with .py file but not with .ipynb file.

So, I just want **to execute the command "runipy -o myfile.ipynb" on Raspberry Pi 4 Boot-up.**
I really need an answer please.

**This would help me a lot. Thanks!**

Comment: your question does not appear to be related to the raspberry pi .... you may be able to get a faster answer at a linux site

Comment: Can you please refer me to one of those sites?

Answer (score 2):

Please take note that using `/etc/rc.local` has limitations due to [Compatibility with SysV](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/). We have seen many problems here on this site using it. Following the recommendation of the developers from **systemd** you should avoid using it.

You should use a **systemd** Unit file to start your program at bootup. You will find many answers here on this site. Please have a look at the Tag [systemd-startup](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/systemd-startup). If you run into problems with this, so please edit your question and add the Unit file for your service you have tried.

Comment: Thankyou for you answer. But i also used the systemd method to start my .ipynb file at boot up by enabling the service. This also did not run the file. I can't figure out how to execute my program at startup. Can you please elaborate the systemd method for runipy command here in a detailed form, since that method is also for the .py files. I think it's 'runipy' that might be the problem here.

Comment: @AfaqKhan As I suggested in the answer, please add the Unit file, you have tried, to your question.

Comment: Okay, i will add it in some time,since i delete everything i create for one method respectively if it does not work out, to save myself from running into problems while trying other methods and to make a fresh start for new methods :)

Answer (score 1):

Try running that `runipy` command using the fully qualified name, e.g. `/usr/local/bin/runipy`. `/etc/rc.local` may not have the same `$PATH` as your login shell. If this command has to do with Python, try setting a sane Python environment as well (`$PYTHONPATH`, `$PYTHONHOME`, etc.)

If that doesn't help, you'll have to diagnose what "cannot seem to execute this command" actually means. Does the process fail to start? Does it exit with an error code? Which one? Are there any error messages?